# Mat::load: couldn't read error

Tags: armadillo

I'm trying to load an Armadillo binary file with Armadillo `mat::load()` function.

On Windows it worked fine.

I recently converted my code to Linux and now it gives me the error: `Mat::load(): couldn't read <filename>`.

The file exist in that location and I have read permissions.

What else can be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loading and saving binary files in Armadillo is currently platform specific. In other words, if you save in Windows, you may not be able to load the file in Linux. However, if you save in Linux, it will also load in Linux.

Comment: Good to know, but I tried reading now from an ascii file and still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a trailing newline char in my filename string.

In windows it didn't matter, but Linux is picky.